# Excel - Stop Calculating after it first gets a value

Tags: excel

I'm having a spreedsheet where I have a formula in column L, however, once the column have made its calculation ones I want it to stop calculating and just hold the value it got assign. Is there any way to do that?

The reason why I want to accomplish this is because now if I change a value in say K2, the values of all the cells in column L after 2 gets recalculated and get assign new values which I dont want to happen, I want it to have the same values as it first got assign.

So something like, =if(isempty(K2),"",L1+K1, (STOP UPDATING))

So if I put something in K2 it makes the calculation and then just hold that value without updating it on future changes.

I tried to refer to the same cell if the cell after in the column get assign any value. So say, =if(L3="",L1+K1,L2). Where it should refer to itself if L3 have a value.

Comment: Paste dome data sample and desired result.

Comment: You  can use VBA to do this; replacing the formula with the calculation results.

Comment: So, after changing the value in cell K2 then select the column or the cells you no longer wish to change and do copy paste.special values manually.